# add ResourcePermission in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I trying to Add multiple Resource permission.

```
for(int jndex = 0; jndex < rowIds.length; jndex ++) {

        if(rowIds[jndex] > 0) {

            ResourceAction resourceAction = ResourceActionLocalServiceUtil
            .fetchResourceAction(rowIds[jndex]);
            String className = resourceAction.getName();
            long classNameId = ClassNameLocalServiceUtil
                            .getClassNameId(className);

            ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.addResourcePermission(
                serviceContext.getCompanyId(), 
                className, ResourceConstants.SCOPE_GROUP, 
                String.valueOf(classNameId), 
                role.getRoleId(), resourceAction.getActionId()
                );

            _log.info("rowIds[jndex]  " + rowIds[jndex] +
                " resourceAction.getActionId() " + resourceAction.getActionId());
        }
    }
```

when length of rowIds larger than 1. It just add ONE resource permission to database.

Comment: You did not mention the problem!

Comment: What does `rowIds` array contain?

Comment: rowIds contain id of resourceAction (in resourceaction table).when rowIds contain 2 item and more, I want to resourcpermission add all. But now, it's just insert one resourcepermission to database

Comment: add `else { _log.info("found a rowId <= 0: " + rowIds[jndex]); }` after the `if` block and execute again.